# flex row with dynamic height add bottom space then start shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have dynamic height **row: max-height: 100px;**

Then items start shrink appear free space on bottom row, how i can fix this?

[image]

```
.imagesRow {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 600px;
}

img {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfm23o0u/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nzw6sdyx/ display:block / vertical-align

Comment: thx ! its work. go to read reference question )